# How to display 0 for missing records while blending data Google Data Studio?

Tags: business-intelligence, looker-studio

I am attempting to blend two data sources in Google Data Studio:

**Data Source 1.** weekly sales numbers by market (example below)

| ID | WeekEndingDate | Market | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7/17/2022 | Utah | $400 |
| 2 | 7/17/2022 | Arizona | $500 |
| 3 | 7/17/2022 | Colorado | $600 |
| 4 | 7/17/2022 | Dallas Fort Worth | $700 |
| 5 | 7/10/2022 | Utah | $400 |
| 6 | 7/10/2022 | Colorado | $300 |
| 7 | 7/10/2022 | Dallas Fort Worth | $800 |
| 8 | 7/10/2022 | Arizona | $600 |
| 9 | 7/10/2022 | Utah | $500 |
| 10 | 7/10/2022 | Colorado | $100 |

**Data Source 2.** weekly budget by market (Example below)

| WeekEndingDate | Market | Sales Budget |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7/17/2022 | Utah | $5000 |
| 7/17/2022 | Arizona | $4000 |
| 7/17/2022 | Colorado | $3000 |
| 7/17/2022 | Dallas Fort Worth | $2000 |
| 7/17/2022 | Tennessee | $1000 |
| 7/17/2022 | Oregon | $1000 |
| 7/10/2022 | Utah | $5000 |
| 7/10/2022 | Arizona | $4000 |
| 7/10/2022 | Colorado | $300 |
| 7/10/2022 | Dallas Fort Worth | $2000 |
| 7/10/2022 | Tennessee | $1000 |
| 7/10/2022 | Oregon | $1000 |

**What I Want in Data Studio Table**  (Example below) I have bolded the rows that I am unable to get in my table. The rest of the rows I am able to get perfectly.

| WeekEndingDate | Market | Sales Budget | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/17/2022 | Utah | $5000 | $400 |
| 7/17/2022 | Arizona | $4000 | $500 |
| 7/17/2022 | Colorado | $3000 | $600 |
| 7/17/2022 | Dallas Fort Worth | $2000 | $700 |
| **7/17/2022** | **Tennessee** | **$1000** | **$0** |
| **7/17/2022** | **Oregon** | **$1000** | **$0** |
| 7/10/2022 | Utah | $5000 | $900 |
| 7/10/2022 | Arizona | $4000 | $600 |
| 7/10/2022 | Colorado | $3000 | $400 |
| 7/10/2022 | Dallas Fort Worth | $2000 | $800 |
| **7/10/2022** | **Tennessee** | **$1000** | **$0** |
| **7/10/2022** | **Oregon** | **$1000** | **$0** |

**My blend in data studio**

[image: Blend Between DS1 and DS2]

**What I am able to generate in Data Studio** Please see this data as a reference for the screenshot below https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nZbuX7x--BoO63sDmv4b3NaeL3ixaInl4IWsyXfnLLo/edit#gid=1617242817

[image]

I have successfully created an inner join blend between the two data sources linking the week date and the market. The data is pulling almost perfectly and I am like 98% done, however, what I am having trouble with is that data source #2 has weekly budget records for weeks that do not exist in data source #1 and those weeks will not show up on my table in data studio (ex. week ending 7/17/2022 for Tennessee budget is $2,000 but no sales were made in week ending 7/17/2022 in Tennessee, therefore, there are no records of sales for week ending 7/17/2022 in data source 1).

I currently have in a simple table each weeks sales and budget in two different columns but week 7/17/2022 is missing because there are no records for week ending 7/17/2022 in data source 1 to match the week in source 2. I need to display that week 7/17/2022's budget for tennessee is $2,000 and that there were $0 in sales for that week. Does anyone have an ideas on how I can accomplish this?

PS - I attempted a full outer join of the two data sources and there was no difference.

**UPDATE** - sorry for the lack of information at first. I have compiled some data that will hopefully help clarify this issue and you can find the data here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nZbuX7x--BoO63sDmv4b3NaeL3ixaInl4IWsyXfnLLo/edit?usp=sharing

You can also find a sample data studio report that you can view how I have it currently setup based on the sample data in the google sheet link above: https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/adfc3ee5-6a9f-4c57-b66f-cff27e91850e

I have also added some sample tables directly on Stackoverflow for a quicker sample view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### 0) Summary

1. Looks at the issue
2. Solution #1 - Left outer join

### 1) Background and Issue

To visualise the issue and let's focus on the values where `WeekEndingDate` is **Jul 17, 2022** and look at the values in the `Market` field:

| WeekEndingDate | Market | Data Source 1 | Data Source 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jul 17, 2022 | Utah | ✅ | ✅ |
| Jul 17, 2022 | Arizona | ✅ | ✅ |
| Jul 17, 2022 | Dallas Fort Worth | ✅ | ✅ |
| Jul 17, 2022 | Colorado | ✅ | ✅ |
| Jul 17, 2022 | Oregon | ✅ | ✅ |
| Jul 17, 2022 | Nevada | ❌ | ✅ |
| Jul 17, 2022 | Tennessee | ❌ | ✅ |

As indicated by the ❌, two Market values (Nevada and Tennessee) are available in Data Source 2 but not in Data Source 1

### 2) Suggestion #1: Left Outer Join

Shift the data sources so that data source 2 is on the left and data source 1 is on the right and then left outer join:

#### 2.1) Blend Fields

| Description | Table 1 | Table 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Data Source**: | 2 | 1 |
| **Dimension 1**: | `WeekEndingDate` | `WeekEndingDate` |
| **Dimension 2**: | `Market` | `Market` |
| **Metric 1**: | `Sales Budget` | `Sales` |
| **Date Range**: | `WeekEndingDate` (Auto) | `WeekEndingDate` (Auto) |
| **Image**: | [image: table_1_blend_left] | [image: table_2_blend_left] |

#### 2.2) Join Configuration

| Description | Table 1 Table 2 |
| --- | --- |
| **Join Operator**: | Left Outer |
| **Join Condition 1**: | `WeekEndingDate (Data Source 2)` `WeekEndingDate (Data Source 1)` |
| **Join Condition 2**: | `Market (Data Source 2)` `Market (Data Source 1)` |
| **Image**: | [image: join_config] |

Publicly editable Google Data Studio report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KpiWY3JgRh5OuFr0PUzJ8AFyiK7PvOrqhKzE-yFLiDc/edit?usp=sharing) data source) to elaborate: